# Error when installing fscrypt latest version 0.3.1

Tags: f2fs

I have downloaded the latest version of the fscrypt v0.3.1, and installed all the runtime dependencies as mentioned in the README of fscrypt. When running make command in the fscrypt source folder, the following error shows:

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
`make: *** [Makefile:96: bin/fscrypt] Error 2`

Comment: There's an earlier error message that's causing this one

Answer (score 0):

You need to install:

1. `libpam0g-dev` on Debian based distro.
2. `pam-devel` and `gcc` on RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the `fscrypt` is implemented in Go Language.

How I solved my problem?

I had to include the `CGO_CFLAGS`, `CGO_LDCFLAGS` to the `GO_ENV_SETUP`, as shown below:

```
GO_ENV_SETUP := GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm CGO_ENABLED=1 PKG_CONFIG=$(PKG_CONFIG_PATH_TARGET) PKG_ROOT=$(PKG_ROOT_TARGET) CGO_CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' CGO_LDFLAGS='$(LDFLAGS)' CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' LDFLAGS='$(LDFLAGS)'
GO_ENV_SETUP += GO_FLAGS='-x'
```